# Tangent plane to $f(x, y)= x^3 - x \, \ln y + y^2 + 3 y \ln x + 5$ in $(1,1,z_0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let be $f(x, y)= x^3 - x \, \ln y + y^2 + 3 y \ln x + 5$

Calculate  $z_0=f(1,1)$

I calculate that and gives me $7$ I mean $f(1,1)=7$

and  give the tangent plane to $f(x, y)= x^3 - x \, \ln y + y^2 + 3 y \ln x + 5$ in $(1,1,z_0)$

But I think the point (1,1,7) is not in $f(x, y)= x^3 - x \, \ln y + y^2 + 3 y \ln x + 5$

Then how can I calculate the tangent plane?

Comment: The graph of your function $f$ is the set of points $(x,y,z)$, where $z=f(x,y)$. Hence, the point $(1,1,7)$ belongs to the graph, since $7=f(1,1)$. Now you need to know what is the formula (and why) for the tangent plane attached to the graph of $f$ at a given point $(x,y,f(x,y))$.

Comment: Does I really need calculate $z_0$? I mean I calculate the gradient of $f$ and it gives me the vector $[3x^2-ln(y)+\frac{3y}{x},2y+3ln(x)-\frac{x}{y}]$ is a vector of two components and I need to calculate the gradient in the point $(1,1,7)$ but I just can use 1,1 right?

Comment: I think you have confusing the concepts. The gradient at the point $(1,1,7)$ of what function? Look for the tangent plane of a level surface at a point and compare with the tangent plane of the graph of a real function of to variables at a point.

Comment: @PQH The gradient at the point $(1,1,7)$ of $f(x, y)= x^3 - x \, \ln y + y^2 + 3 y \ln x + 5$ it gives me the normal vector $[6,1]$ and then I get the plane $ 6x+y=7 $

Comment: I insist, look for the proper definitions and you will realize the missing point. You can't evaluate the gradient of $f$ whose domain lives in $\mathbb{R}^2$ at a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @PQH Ok now I see, It will be the gradient of $f(x,y)=z_0=f(x,y)-z_0=f(x,y,z)$ in the point $(1,1,7)$ so now I have the vector $[6,1,-1]$ so I get the plane $6x+y=0$

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the plane tangent to $z=f(x,y)$ at point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is$$z  = f\left( {{x_0},{y_0}} \right) + {f_x}\left( {{x_0},{y_0}} \right)\left( {x - {x_0}} \right) + {f_y}\left( {{x_0},{y_0}} \right)\left( {y - {y_0}} \right)$$
$$f_x(x,y)=3 x^2+\frac{3 y}{x}-\log y;\;f_y(x,y)=-\frac{x}{y}+3 \log x+2 y$$
$$z=7+6(x-1)+(y-1)\to z=6x+y$$